# Python Error: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 4 elements

Tags: python, pandas

Inherited a code in my new job, it creates columns but then says they are not created.

Error on final_clust.columns = ['prod_id', 'clusters', 'facs', 'agg_demand_2']
Error is ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 4 elements

```
products = []
clusters = []
facs = []
demand = []

for prod in clust_df['product'].unique():
    for fac in clust_df[clust_df['product'] == prod]['close_facs']:
         demand.append(int(agg_demand_ext_2_wh_to_wh_lookup[(agg_demand_ext_2_wh_to_wh_lookup['prod_id']       == prod) & (agg_demand_ext_2_wh_to_wh_lookup['chosen_fac'] == fac)]['agg_dem_two_whs']))
            products.append(prod)
            clusters.append(int(clust_df[(clust_df['product'] == prod) & (clust_df['close_facs'] == fac)]        ['cluster']))
        facs.append(fac)
        
final_clust = pd.DataFrame(zip(products, clusters, facs, demand))
final_clust.columns = ['prod_id', 'clusters', 'facs', 'agg_demand_2']`
```

I havent been able to try anything cause to me the code has 4 elements defined.
Im new to python so be gentle.

Comment: Can't reproduce: `df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1], [2], [3], [4])); df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` raises no error.

Comment: Since it causes no error could it mean my data inputs are causing the error?